# scale2x in GameMaker: Studio

Tags: graphics, shader, scale, game-maker, glsles

I am using GameMaker: Studio to create a fighting game. I want to implement a scale2x algorithm using a GLSL ES (the default) shader. I'm new to shaders, and I can't find any solutions online. Essentially I want a shader that goes from this:

[image: Original sprite]

To this:

[image: Sprite enhanced using scale2x algorithm]

Could you teach me how to make such a shader? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here's the scale2x website: http://www.scale2x.it/

Answer (score 1):

I can't teach you how to make shaders over stackoverflow, but I will tell you the operation you are looking for is called an affine transform. "Affine" just means that straight lines stay straight. Most programming environments including all variants of opengl use matrix transformations to do just the type of manipulation you are talking about. Since there are tons of ways to use a matrix to transform something, just start with the simplest case. In order to scale something up in 2D, like your are asking, uses a scale matrix that looks something like this:

```
[   xScale    0      0    ]
[     0     yScale   0    ]
[     0       0      1    ]

// where scale is a percentage.
// 100% = 1.0
```

If you can create such a matrix and use the code you have to perform a "affine transform" using that matrix should do the trick.

Keep in mind, this will scale up every point/pixel in the image. It does not necessarily add information to the picture. So if you have a low resolution image, it will look really bad when you scale it up.

The issue of creating information in image space is interpolation and extrapolation.
Usually it is called "Resampling" which is also related to "Convolution".